# How can I pass a string value to another jsp page using session.setAttribute ("", table) why it's not executing? "select * from " + table + "";?

Tags: java, jsp

Why mysql query string query ="select * from " + table + "";` is not working the table name is coming from another jsp page.

And why session. setAttribute ("", "table");` is not working to import string from jsp to jsp?

I have two jsp file in my code one is for selection of table for username and password to get login the file name is statement.jsp and other file statement is for showing data in a table that is selected in statement3.jsp. I want to use table string in another jsp page to show that table.

**error**

```
   String query ="select * from " + table + ""; //for selection of table

   session.setAttribute("", "table");  //To pass String table from statement.jsp to statement3.jsp to show table.
```

**[image]statement3.jsp**

```
  <%  
     ResultSet rs = null;
     session.setAttribute("", "table"); 

     String query ="select * from " + table + "";

     rs=st.executeQuery(query);
 %>
```

---

**statement.jsp**

```
<% 
 ResultSet rs = null;
 String name=request.getParameter("username");
 String abc=request.getParameter("password");       

 String gender = request.getParameter("gender");

 if (gender != null) {
 String table = gender.equals("teacher") ? "teacher2" : "student";

 out.println(table);  

 String query ="select * from " + table + " where username='"+name+"' AND password='"+abc+"'";
 rs=st.executeQuery(query); 
 out.println(rs);
 if(rs.next()) 
 {
   response.sendRedirect("statement3.jsp");
 }
   else
{
  response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
 }}
%>
```

`Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:93)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:435)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:298)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:277)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:265)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:302)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)`

Comment: You don't have a variable called `table` in statement3.jsp, so why do you expect that code to compile?

Comment: As for `setAttribute ("", "table")`: The attribute should have a name (first parameter), and your value is always the string `"table"`, not the value of variable `table`. You do know that `"table"` and `table` is not the same thing, right?

Comment: Because i want to get table with session.setAttribute("", table); from statement.jsp in statement3.jsp.

Comment: @Andreas still no working with it `session.setAttribute("",table);`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to put the value of the variable `table` in the session you can do this:

```
String table = "whateverTableNameYouWant";
session.setAttribute("mySessionVariableName", table);
```

If you want to read that value in another jsp, you can do this:

```
String table = (String)session.getAttribute("mySessionVariableName");
```